# How to use OOP with php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

As the title says, how can I use oop with php and jquery. I create some objects at the php sides.

This is how they look:

```
class PurchaseOrder {
    private $id;
    private $credId;
    private $orderReference; 
    private $purchaseRows = array();

    /**
     * PurchaseOrder constructor.
     * @param $id
     * @param $credId
     * @param $orderReference
     */
    public function __construct($id, $credId, $orderReference)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->credId = $credId;
        $this->orderReference = $orderReference;
    }

    public function addPurchaseRow(PurchaseRow $row){
        array_push($this->purchaseRows, $row);
    }

    public function getPurchaseRow($index){
        return $this->purchaseRows[$index];
    }

    public function getOrderReference(){
        return $this->orderReference;
    }

}
```

And the purchase row is the same principle, the purchase row is just a order row. I create the objects and append them to the frontend.

Some portion of the html:

```
<table class="order-table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Reference</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <?php
     echo "<tr> <td>" . $PurchaseOrder->getOrderReference . "</td> </tr>"
     ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This works as expected. But now the part where I don't know how to do it. I I want to display the rows in a order when I click at a row at the table. I know the rows because they are in my object. But the object is gone at the frontend if I understand it correctly? So how can I retrieve the order rows from the PurchaseOrder object at the frontend?

Comment: How many orders are you displaying? Maybe it's easier to print out all the variables with php like you did with the order reference. Put the order rows in a div per order. Then toggle show/hide of the divs with jquery. Otherwise you would have to go through an ajax call to fetch the data from your object, because you are right that the frontend (jquery) can not fetch that.  See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Store whatever you need in data attributes on each row

Comment: @LvS Around 200 orders with each around 80 lines per order.

Comment: are you open to using a plugin ?

Comment: That should not be a problem. You could always use pagination. Wether you store the rows in jquery data attributes or print out everything and toggle view, the data is available to the client anyway. In that way it doesn't differ much. And if these orders are going to be accessed by the same person, that is no problem then. I think that is much easier then making an ajax call to another php script to go fetch your data.